# Unexpected results when using the --app-dir flag vs specifying the full path to main.py when starting a FastAPI server with uvicorn

Tags: python-import, fastapi, gunicorn, uvicorn

I cloned the following repo to demonstrate what I mean: https://github.com/rednafi/fastapi-nano

I followed the steps in the readme (make venv, install reqs) and I'm ready to start the server.

When I run `uvicorn app.main:app`, everything works as expected.

But if I run the command `uvicorn --app-dir app main:app` I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`.

I can fix this last error by running `export PYTHONPATH="$PWD"` but I do not understand why this is necessary in the first place. Can someone explain this to me?